# Push query to ksqlDB not returning final result in first result row

Tags: confluent-platform, ksqldb

I'm trying to get the count of events in a ksqlDB table within an arbitrary time window.
The table `my_table` was created with a `WINDOW SESSION`.
It is important to note the query is being run after all data was processed, and the ksqlDB server is basically doing nothing.
My query looks something like this

```
count(*) as count
FROM my_table 
WHERE WINDOWSTART < (1602010972370 + 5000) AND WINDOWEND > 1602010972370
group by 1 emit changes;
```

Running this kind of query will very often return one result row, and immediately after a second result row with the actual "final" result.
It doesn't look like its a result of values in the table not being "settled" yet, because if I repeat the same query (as many times as I want) I get the same exact behavior.

I'm assuming there is some configuration value which will let ksqlDB to wait just a little longer (in the order of one second) before it returns the result, so I could get the final result in the first row?

BTW using `emit final` will not work on the query itself since it only apply to "windowed querys"